# SQL query performance explanation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-optimization, database-optimization

I have this query(of course with couple joins across tables and some views which I will call x for simplicity).

1. Case 1 : `select * from x`  -> returns in 10 sec, still acceptable,
   fairly heavy on joins and lot of data
2. Case 2 : `select * from x where userid = 1` -> returns in 0-1 sec,
   good enough
3. Case 3 : using SP : `if @userid = -1 select * from x else select
       from x where userid = @userid`
       -> now calling sp with paramenter userid 1 should return on 0-1 sec as it should be comparable to case 2 but in fact it returns in
   10
       sec.

   Now, parameter masking OR WITH RECOMPILE on sp  OR OPTION
   (recompile) on query with where clause doesn't help, What makes the
   SP run faster with `userid = something` is putting OPTION(recompile)
   on the first part of the SP ie on the query without where clause. :
4. Case 4 : using SP : `if @userid = -1 select * from x option
   (recompile) else select * from x where userid = @userid`

Any explanation?

I can guess earlier it was using optimization based of query without where clause even for the query with where clause, but why is that?

Comment: Please use the code block for code. You should get used to it after 65 question.

Comment: thanks Nelson for editing! sorry about not putting it in codeblocks.

Comment: Are you asking us to explain your queries? Why not just look at the Execution Plan in SSMS?

Comment: No, I'm asking the reason for improved performance by adding option(recompile) on the query without the where clause

Comment: I mean, I'm guessing it might be figured from execution plans, which I did look into and can't pin point what's the reason. A lot of questions (on stackoverflow or otherwise) could be understood by just looking and analyzing execution plans in depth. But then why would I post the question, if you're asking me to attach execution plans here, then that's a different story.

Comment: Please post the execution plans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stored procedures cache execution plans, so they don't have the overhead of recompiling a query every time the SP is called.  This is particularly important when using stored procedures for transactions.  It is much less important whent the queries are running for several seconds.

When a query takes parameters the stored procedure must decide what values to optimize for.  I am guessing that your SQL Server recognizes the two queries as being identical, and is using the same cached plan for them.  It is optimizing the plan based on the first query.  This is speculation, but it would explain what you are seeing.

You can readily fix this with the following version of the query:

```
select *
from x
where @userid = -1 or userid = @userid
option (recompile)
```